# Why does an ASP.NET MVC parameter that is passed as whitespace become null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In a partially completed feature I'm picking up that was stagnant for a year and whose author is no longer around, I have an endpoint declared as

```
[HttpGet("search")]
public ActionResult GetId([FromQuery] SearchQuery query) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.PartialDescription) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.PartialReference))
        return BadRequest(new { Reason = "Cannot search as no string values were supplied" });

    // performs query
}
```

with this model

```
public class SearchQuery
{
    public SearchQuery();

    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Reference. May not exceed 50 characters.")]
    public string PartialReference { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Description. May not exceed 250 characters.")]
    public string PartialDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I thought the use of IsNullOrEmpty instead of IsNullOrWhiteSpace in the guard clause might be a gap and confirmed by writing a failing unit test that passed after updating the guard clause to use IsNullOrWhiteSpace.

But when I tested it through Swagger by entering a single space in `partialReference` and `partialDescription` I found that the action never receives parameters with just whitespace, but with null.

Swagger showed the URL as `https://localhost:5001/search?partialReference=%20&partialDescription=%20` including the spaces as parameter values, so I was surprised when query.PartialReference and query.PartialDescription passed into the endpoint method were null rather than single spaces.

Can anyone explain why this happens? I'm assuming this is caused somehow by validation middleware. Assuming I actually needed to be able to pass whitespace to a parameter (which I don't in this case) what would I need to do to enable that?

Comment: Do the URLs work if you pass an actual string though? Just ensuring the binding is correct. Also what if you pass `+` through instead?

Comment: Yes, the action works fine and sending through actual text performs the database query and returns either Ok with the found items or NotFound. I'm not sure whether `+` should have some significance but it behaves as any other text would, resulting in NotFound as no items contain that character.

Comment: I think it might be a defect see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29948) open github issue

Comment: Thank you @SelmirAljic, I think that might well be the reason which would explain why I couldn't find anything in documentation. Fortunately it's not a problem for me, just something I was curious about.